# IIS 404 page is shown instead of Wordpress one

Tags: wordpress, iis

I have set up wordpress with IIS on my personal computer, when I access an invalid page instead of getting Wordpress 404 error page I get IIS default 404 error page. Is there a way to make the IIS server to use the Wordpress one?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the Codex here `https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page` all you should need to do is drop a file called `404.php` into your child theme's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that is there any Permalink Settings are the issue.
Install Url rewrite module in IIS using web platform installer or [manually](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) if not installed.
Add below url rewrite rule in your web.config file.

```
    <?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name=“wordpress” patternSyntax=“Wildcard”>
<match url=“*”/>
<conditions>
<add input=“{REQUEST_FILENAME}” matchType=“IsFile” negate=“true”/>
<add input=“{REQUEST_FILENAME}” matchType=“IsDirectory” negate=“true”/>
</conditions>
<action type=“Rewrite” url=“index.php”/>
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Set the correct file permissions on the site folder for the IIS_IUSRS and IUSR.

Restart the IIS server.

Comment: that just broke my iis :(